# PHP Sending html with mail() - certain servers receive as text

Tags: php, email

I've searched a lot but could not find any solutions for this.
after changing my code for hours i tried the example from php.net and it acts the same.

if i send it to my gmail address everything look fine,
if i send it to another server it does not render it as html.
i tried about 8 servers and  4 suffer from this issue

this is the code (php example):

```
// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

**this is the "show original" from gmail (gmail is only the client, mail comes from php server), message is not displayed correctly - html is raw:**

```
Delivered-To: XXX
Received: by 10.220.35.74 with SMTP id o10csp285028vcd;
        Sun, 9 Dec 2012 03:18:35 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.220.238.139 with SMTP id ks11mr6865773vcb.49.1355051914996;
        Sun, 09 Dec 2012 03:18:34 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: best guess record for domain of transitioning             unknown does not designate 82.80.232.249 as permitted sender) client-ip=82.80.232.249;
Received: by 10.230.67.134 with POP3 id r6mf4415353vbi.4;
            Sun, 09 Dec 2012 03:18:34 -0800 (PST)
X-Gmail-Fetch-Info: gideon@example.com 5 mail.example.com 110 gideon@example.com
Received: from [82.80.232.249] by mail.example.com (ArGoSoft Mail Server .NET v.1.0.8.4)         with ESMTP (EHLO web9.wishosting.net)
    for <gideon@example.com>; Sun, 09 Dec 2012 13:18:02 +0200
Received: by web9.wishosting.net (Postfix, from userid 1168)
    id C82D03EE2EC; Sun,  9 Dec 2012 13:18:23 +0200 (IST)
        To: gideon@example.com, wez@example.com
Subject: Birthday Reminders for August
    X-PHP-Script: example.com/lp/mailtest.php for 89.139.28.204
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Sun, 09 Dec 2012 13:18:02 +0200
Message-ID: <x0otq4xc1dcboohp09122012011802@EAWEB1>
SPF-Received: none
X-FromIP: 82.80.232.249
From: gideon@example.com

Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>

From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>

Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com

Message-Id: <20121209111823.C82D03EE2EC@web9.wishosting.net>
Date: Sun,  9 Dec 2012 13:18:23 +0200 (IST)



    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
              <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
          <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And that is said by @Cthulhu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ivan's comment is correct!

Try below example which uses phpmailer lib.

```
<?php
//phpmailer lib
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

try {
    $mail->AddAddress('mary@example.com', 'Mary');
    $mail->AddAddress('kelly@example.com', 'Kelly');
    $mail->SetFrom('birthday@example.com', 'Birthday Reminder');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@example.com', 'No-reply');
    $mail->Subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!\nPerson:Joe BirthDay:3rd Aug 1970\nPerson:Sally BirthDay:17th Aug 1973\n'; 
    $mail->MsgHTML('
        <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
            </tr>
        </table>'
    );

    $mail->Send();

    echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
?>
```

PHPMailer can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list

Samples located in https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/ExamplesPage

Comment: i did try phpMailer but had other issues with it, if i can't make the regular mail() work i'll try again. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This depends of email reader that will display the message.

Gmail and most modern email clients (like MS Outlook, Thunderbird, Evolution...) will render html if it has html content, some older readers will render it as a plain text since they are not capable of rendering html (like squirrel or horde).

In order for email to be properly rendered in any reader you have to put in email body both plain text and html version of email.

Best way to do it is to use **PHPmailer, SwiftMail and other wrappers for email in php**, but if you really wish to do it yourself [try this](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/2959/sending-htmlplain-text-emails).

Also, note that some readers will have problems in displaying various html elements like divs, and css rules. **It is best to stick with tags and css what MS Outlook can render.**

Comment: @rizon You should make email content compatible with older readers, although there are not that many of them left out there, but still. This means that alongside html content, you should put plain text version of the same. Check the Kasun's example with PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting MIME boundaries

```
// generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
       $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

       // now we'll build the message headers
       $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
       "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
          "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
          " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

       // here, we'll start the message body.
       // this is the text that will be displayed
       // in the e-mail
       $message="This is an example";

       // next, we'll build the invisible portion of the message body
       // note that we insert two dashes in front of the MIME boundary 
       // when we use it
       $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
          "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
       $message . "\n\n";
```